# Permanently Import an Excel CSV File to Mathematica

Tags: notebooks, data

I had imported the file already and everything is working from my computer, but when the notebook is opened in a different computer none all the commands work properly. 
Thanks. 
[image]

Comment: First you do `data=Import["file.csv"]`, then use `Iconize[data]` to preserve it in the notebook.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but doesn't work. The Iconize stays blue after evaluation.

Comment: How does it not work...?

Comment: I forget to tell you that the file has 14 columns and 26884 rows. Does that make a difference?

Comment: You forgot to tell us a lot of things. This is incredibly vague. As a start, which version of Mathematica are you working on?

Comment: Sorry for that. The version is 11.2.

Comment: `Iconize` was introduced in 11.3, but it does precisely what you want.

Comment: I also noticed that the MeanCI command does not work.

Comment: Thanks I will try to update to that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with a team in diverse geographics areas and we often are using imported documents and then manipulating them in Mathematica.  We have found the easiest thing to do is to `Import` the file and then use `CloudPut` and `CloudGet` to access it later.

So in your case, the code would simply be:

```
CloudPut[Import["D:\\data.csv"],"importdata", Permissions -> "Public"]
```

> CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/USERNAME/importdata"]

```
data=CloudGet["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/USERNAME/importdata"]
```

If you are sharing the notebook, be sure to set the properties of the `CloudPut` / `Import` cell to not evaluate.

The advantage/disadvantage to this is that you can overwrite the data that others will access.  Can be a problem if you do this accidentally, but can be a good thing if you want to update the underlying dataset and still have everything run with the new inputs.

I set my permissions as public, but depending on what you are working on, the appropriateness of this will vary.

**Another Option:**

If working with a `CloudObject` isn't an option for you, you can also import the file, then put `data=` in front of the output and evaluate.  Then you then set the cell as an initialization cell and hide it.  It is a bit ugly if people go digging, but it works.

More on initialization cells here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithInitializationCells.html

Comment: Awesome! I used CloudPut and CloudGet and I could evaluate the file in any computer.